# How to match an input value to the whole range of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, input

I'm coding a quiz where the user is supposed to fill in an answer and if it matches with one of the correct answers in an array the field turns green, otherwise it turns red. This is what works:

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
var id = document.getElementById("id");
 if (id.value == arr[0] 
     || id.value == arr[1] 
     || id.value == arr[2] 
     || id.value == arr[3]){id.style.backgroundColor = "#83C183";}
     else {id.style.backgroundColor = "#E06969";}
```

But I want to get rid of:

```
 if (id.value == arr[0] || id.value == arr[1] || id.value == arr[2] || id.value == arr[3])
```

I tried to iterate the array with a `for` loop:

```
 var arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
 var id = document.getElementById("id");
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ 
      if (id.value == arr[i]){id.style.backgroundColor = "#83C183";}
      else {id.style.backgroundColor = "#E06969";}
      }
```

But it returns only `"c"` as being true. How do I select all items in the array in this case?

Comment: Added a working snippet with cleaner code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39158841/1409180)

Comment: `bkgColor = arr.includes(id.value) ? "green" : "red"`

Answer (score 1):

Create a flag variable, that is set whenever it matches with an item in the array. Then check this flag to determine whether to set the background color to green or red.

Sample code:

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
var id = document.getElementById("id");
var flag = false;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ 
    if (id.value == arr[i]) 
    {
        flag = true;          
        break;
    }
}

if (flag) {id.style.backgroundColor = "#83C183";}
else {id.style.backgroundColor = "#E06969";}
```

Comment: Looping is not the cleanest approach, when there's things like the javascript `filter` function IMO

Comment: A 'break;' would also help.

Comment: @MarkusMitterauer Yes you're right. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `indexOf` method to check if answer exists in array or not.

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
var id = document.getElementById("id");
if(arr.indexOf(id.value) > -1)
 id.style.backgroundColor = "#83C183";
else  
 id.style.backgroundColor = "#E06969";
```

Comment: Checked it out, didn't work for me :( But thanx for your effort

Answer (score 0):

A much cleaner way to implement this is as follows:

```js
function evaluateAnswerFilter() {
  var arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
  var inputEl = document.getElementById("id");
  var truth = arr.filter(function(option) {
    return option === inputEl.value
  });
  truth.length ? inputEl.style.backgroundColor = "#83C183" :
    inputEl.style.backgroundColor = "#E06969"
}

function evaluateAnswerIncludes() {
  var arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
  var inputEl = document.getElementById("id");
  arr.includes(inputEl.value) ? inputEl.style.backgroundColor = "#83C183" :
    inputEl.style.backgroundColor = "#E06969"
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input name="id" id="id" type="text" />
  <button onclick="evaluateAnswerFilter()">Evaluate with Filter</button>
  <button onclick="evaluateAnswerIncludes()">Evaluate with Includes</button>

</body>
```

Comment: Dustin, this snippet is actually in the function already, I was just lazy to give all picture, will it work like function inside function?

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question. Most functions can be nested within functions in JS.

 My suggestion is to use the `filter` function on the array, which is cleaner than running for loops (which are infamous for underperformance). Even better, you could use something like `Array.prototype.includes`

Comment: Updated the snippet. Could you check now?